# NoMethodError: undefined method `created_at' for in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

So here is a object I retrieved from the ActiveRecord  `other = [#<Referrer id: 16, name: "Other", published: true, created_at: "2011-07-11 16:22:00", updated_at: "2011-07-11 16:22:00">]`

Why can't I do `other.created_at` while I can do `other.name`?

Here is the model:

```
class Referrer < ActiveRecord::Base
end
```

The error I'm getting:

```
NoMethodError: undefined method `created_at' for #<ActiveRecord::Relation:0x1035763c8>
```

What have I missed?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you'll notice, `other` is actually an `ActiveRecord::Relation` which basically means it's acting like an array of `Referrer` objects. So you can't just call `created_at` on it. You could call `other.first.created_at` or if you want an array of `created_at` dates you could do `other.map(&:created_at)`.

The reason you can call `other.name` is because an `ActiveRecord::Relation` responds to name. But it's a different `name` method than the `name` attribute on your `Referrer` model. `other.name` should return `"Referrer"` instead of `"Other"` right?